# `Cannot read Component` in a React Component npm module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a small set of reusable react components which i am attempting to bundle together into a module.

However when I include them in another product and try to build I get `Cannot read property 'Component' of undefined`. Webpack seems to not have a reference to `_react.Component` yet `_react` does exist.

My components are compiled into a `/dist` directory using the following config:

```
var config = {
    entry: path.resolve('./src/index.jsx'),
    devtool: 'source-map',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('./dist'),
        filename: 'react-components.js'
    },
    externals: {
        react: {
            root: 'React',
            commonjs2: 'react',
            commonjs: 'react',
            amd: 'react',
        },
        'react-dom': {
            root: 'ReactDOM',
            commonjs2: 'react-dom',
            commonjs: 'react-dom',
            amd: 'react-dom',
        },
        'react-bootstrap': {
            root: 'ReactBootstrap',
            commonjs2: 'react-bootstrap',
            commonjs: 'react-bootstrap',
            amd: 'react-bootstrap',
        }
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /(\.jsx|\.js)$/,
                loader: 'babel',
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

I then include them in my other project using `import { Component1, Component2 } from 'react-components'`.

My webpack config for the project I include them in is pretty much the same as above, i've listed the differences below:

```
var config = {
    entry: path.resolve('./src/example.jsx'),
    devtool: 'source-map',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('./src/'),
        filename: 'app.js',
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/src',
    },
    devServer: {
        hot: true,
        inline: true,
        port: 8080,
        historyApiFallback: true,
    },
    externals: {
        'cheerio': 'window',
        'react/lib/ExecutionEnvironment': true,
        'react/lib/ReactContext': true,
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /(\.jsx|\.js)$/,
                loader: 'babel',
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                presets: [
                    'airbnb'
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: Further investigation and I've found its to do with the bundling of React in the components library. If I remove the externals line everything works. However I wouldn't of thought its good practice to build and release with React included when it will be included again in another project?

Comment: Saying that, it compiles without errors but all the imports are `undefined`

Comment: "However I wouldn't of thought its good practice to build and release with React included when it will be included again in another project?" - this is what Webpack's CommonsChunkPlugin is for. It will strip out externals and place into a separate file